# iOS as BLE Peripheral and Central Mode issues

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm creating new app in iOS using BLE (I'm new to BLE Concept) which need to act as both peripheral and central. I have read lot's of question regarding BLE but I could not find solution for my issues. So, how can I overcome with this issues listed below.

(1). iOS as central & android as peripheral - in this case how to identify the device and which is the unique id for that device, even if I found the list of peripherals around my central it does not have a service data which consists of UUID, Major, Minor value in advertisement packets

(2). iOS as peripheral & iOS as central  - in this case how to send service data with UUID, Major, Minor values in advertisement packets and it should be accessible by iOS central

Help me with whats on your mind, even it might be a small hint/note/suggestion it's highly valuable for me. Thanks in advance.

I expect the outcome in both scenario 
(1).iOS central & android peripheral
(2).iOS central & iOS peripheral 
is to read its service data (UUID, Major , Minor), but the actual outcome is empty service data.

Comment: You seem to be confusing BLE central/peripheral with iBeacons.  When the CBCentral discovers a peripheral, you receive a local, unique identifier for that peripheral.  There is no unique identifier that is consistent across iOS devices for discovered peripherals.  You typically identify them by name or some other data you expose via a characteristic.  If you are looking for a beacon by UUID, major and minor then you use Core Location (CLBeaconRegion) on ios.

Comment: Yes, from your comment i could draw line between them. If i'm using Core Location (CLBeaconRegion) on iOS I need to specify same UUID for all the device and will get a list of ibeacon by different major and/or minor values we set. am i right

Comment: When you tell Core Location to look for a beacon you must specific the UUID. You can also specify a specific major and minor to look for. If you specify only the uuid then iOS will let you know about any beacon that is discovered with that UUID. All beacons in a location typically have the same UUID. You can then examine the discoverer major and minor to determine exactly which beacon you have discovered.

Comment: It is also worth notating that an iOS device cannot act as an iBeacon when your app is not in the foreground (ie the active app)

Comment: Yup I'm aware of background restrictions. Now I'm very clear about CLBeaconRegion concept and how to use it in required place. I got new doubt from the above comment for BLE central/peripheral stating that identifying discovered peripherals by its name or some other data  expose via characteristic. So, How to send that data from iOS?